# How to show/print property name of each items/Objects that were taken from database with AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

I am starting to learn how to use Ajax, and get JSON objects from database. 
So far i have this

```
$('.myButton').click(function () {
var printInfo = document.getElementById('printInfo').value;
var load = document.getElementById('Loading');

load.style.display = 'block';
$.ajax({

    'url': ......,
    //The type of request, also known as the "method" in HTML forms
    //Can be 'GET' or 'POST'
    'type': 'GET',


    'success': function (data) {

        document.write(data);

        load.style.display = 'none';
        //pisi tuka html kod
    }
});
```

});

So, when i have those items received from the database it show me like this

> [object Object],[object Object],[object Object]

How to take the property  of each object? Like, if i write pizza, in the input, and to print like "Pepperoni Pizza", "Cheese, pizza","Pan pizza, crust only"

Comment: What is the output of JSON.stringify

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.myButton').click(function () {
var printInfo = document.getElementById('printInfo').value;
var load = document.getElementById('Loading');

load.style.display = 'block';
$.ajax({

    'url': ..... + printInfo,
    //The type of request, also known as the "method" in HTML forms
    //Can be 'GET' or 'POST'
    'type': 'GET',


    'success': function (data) {

        var text = "";

        // Cycle each property in object data
        for (var prop in data) {
            text += "data." + prop + " = " + data[prop] + "<br>";
        }

        document.write(text);

        load.style.display = 'none';
        //pisi tuka html kod
    }
});
});
```

Comment: This is just getting me whole object. I just want to take the property of each object.

Comment: But this is not possible without seeing your json. Can you provide any example of this?